# Different Ressource folder based on profile properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

How can I create include different resource folder based on the profile chosen: 
I have 5 resource Folders 
1. resources_1
2. resources_2
3. resources_3
4. resources_4
5. resources_5

I have the following layout:

```
src/main/resources 
   ressource1_folder    
   ressource2_folder   
   ressource3_folder 

   application.properties
```

Could you guys please show me how to load the folder into classpath based on the profile chosen in application.properties if this is possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: First why do you need different resource folder? What is the purpose of those directories? If this is a spring boot project that sounds wrong...

Comment: I need one for production another one for testing etc..

Comment: The part for production should be in `src/main/resources` and the one for testing in `src/test/resources`... Or even better do not use configuration at all..configure it within the environment....

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add different properties files for your profiles? Spring will pick them up if you name them correctly, like this:

```
application-dev.properties => "dev"-Spring Profile 
application-prod.properties => "prod"-Spring Profile
application-staging.properties => "staging"-Spring Profile
```

and so on and so forth. See also this excellent article on [Properties with Spring and Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I know about this option how can I tell spring wish resource folder to load in the classpath is the main issue I am facing.

Comment: Then you could either [register your properties files via annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#java), where you use PropertySource-Annotation in combination with the Profile-Annotation or [override the config location](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#1-applicationproperties-the-default-property-file).